# VBA Access code that checks if a String has "[", "]" characters

Tags: vba, ms-access

In the main part of my program I have this code:

```
If Me!Proveedor = "BIMBO" Then
    Me!NombreProducto = Left(BuscaNombre("BIMBO", Mid(Me!Producto, InStr(1, Me!Producto, "[") + 1, (InStr(1, Me!Producto, "]")) - (InStr(1, Me!Producto, "[")) - 1)), 50)
```

Nevertheless, when the value of Me!Proveedor has not '[ ]' the code fails.
What I've tried so far is this piece of code:

```
Me!NombreProducto = iif(InStr(1, Me!Producto, "["), Left(BuscaNombre("BIMBO", Mid(Me!Producto, InStr(1, Me!Producto, "[") + 1, (InStr(1, Me!Producto, "]")) - (InStr(1, Me!Producto, "[")) - 1)), 50), Left(BuscaNombre("BIMBO", Me!Producto.text), 50)
```

But Still, if fails. Any idea of why?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `IIF` if you're returning something that's not valid for one of the conditions! Or better yet, don't use `IIF` in VBA at all. Just use a normal *If* statement.

`IIF` evaluates the condition, the *True* part and the *False* part regardless of if the condition is true. The *True* part is invalid if the condition is false in your case.

```
If InStr(1, Me!Producto, "[") Then
     Me!NombreProducto = Left(BuscaNombre("BIMBO", Mid(Me!Producto, InStr(1, Me!Producto, "[") + 1, (InStr(1, Me!Producto, "]")) - (InStr(1, Me!Producto, "[")) - 1)), 50)
Else
     Me!NombreProducto = Left(BuscaNombre("BIMBO", Me!Producto.text), 50)
End If
```